# Add noise texture effect to navbar in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, noise

Is it possible to add a noise layer to a navbar in CSS? Like this one:

[image]

Either with CSS or background-image (without editing in Photoshop or similar.)

```
.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
}
```

Comment: It's best to insert the image into the question instead of pointing to a URL in case the link is unavailable in the future.

Comment: Try this: http://bg.siteorigin.com/

Comment: @MatthewBaker I actually did, but got an error so i linked it instead.

Comment: CSS Background Noise https://coderwall.com/p/m-uwvg/css-background-noise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS currently doesnt support a way to do this reliably (although I think there should be...).  I just wanted to specify, you want a small image, and then just to repeat it.

Here is a site with [many samples](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#)

And here is a [custom generator](http://www.patternify.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Just set a seamless `background-image: url('some-image.png');`. Adding text on top would likely be in a nested element which doesn't have a `background`. Note you can only add gradients and shadows with CSS3 and not noise.

http://jsfiddle.net/AB7nv/

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div with a background image and opacity 0.3 or something over it.

Comment: This will not add noise, but slightly darken the subviews (uniformly, which is not noise)